# If char c = 0x80, why does printf("%d\n", c << 1) output -256?

Tags: c, integer-promotion

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  char c = 0x80;
  printf("%d\n", c << 1);
  return 0;
}
```

The output is `-256` in this case. If I write `c << 0` then the output is `-128`.

I don't understand the logic behind this code.

Comment: See http://c-faq.com/ansi/maindecl.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Already your starting point is problematic:

```
char c = 0x80;
```

If (as seemingly in your case) `char` is a signed type, you are assigning the integer constant `128` to a type that is only guaranteed to hold values up to `127`. Your compiler then may choose to give you some implementation defined value (`-128` in your case I guess) or to issue a range error.

Then you are doing a left shift on that negative value. This gives undefined behavior. In total you have several implementation defined choices plus undefined behavior that determine the outcome:

- signedness of `char`
- the choice of how to convert `128` to `signed char`
- the width of `char`
- the sign representation of `int` (there are three possibilities)
- the choice on how to implement (or not) left shift on negative `int`

It may be a good exercise for you to look up all these case an to see what the different outcomes may be.

In summary some recommendations:

- choose an appropriate constant to initialize a variable
- don't do arithmetic with plain `char`
- don't do left shift on signed types

Comment: Thanku Jens sir for ur answer.

Comment: The first paragraph of the explanation is wrong and can mislead someone inexperienced.  "char c = 0x80;" is fine just like "int c = 0xFFFFFFFF" is fine, but the part that isn't fine is assuming 0x80 will be 128 when char may be signed  (range of -128 to 127, not 0 to 255)

Comment: @B.Nadolson, I don't think that it is misleading. The constant `0x80` is of type `int` and has value `128`. This type and value on the RHS is determined first, and then that type and value is converted to fit the type on the LHS. Trying to initialize a possibly signed variable with a value that doesn't fit the type is a semantic error.

Comment: C99 standard (6.4.4.1) says you are right.  Although it is common to represent a negative number with hex.  Seem I can't reverse the vote.

Comment: @B.Nadolson, never mind for the vote. Yes, this is a common error. But in many cases the error is in fact in the choice of the type, as in this example.

Answer (score 18):

`char` may be signed on your platform, in which case `0x80` represents -128 (assuming two's complement).

When a `char` is used as an operand with the `<<` operator, it is promoted to `int` (still -128).  So when you apply the left-shift, you get -256.  Technically, shifting negative values is <s>implementation-defined</s> undefined, but what you see is typical behaviour.

Comment: I don't think your statement is about `int` promotion is correct. Shift operators don't do promotion, the result type is the type on the left.

Comment: @Jens: To be fair, I only have the C99 standard in front of me.  But it says in section 6.5.7: "The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands."

Comment: I didn't realize left-shifting negative values was undefined, but apparently it is.  From §6.5.7.4 of the C99 standard, regarding the expression `E1 << E2`: "If `E1` has a signed type and nonnegative value, and `E1 × 2^E2` is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 3):

`c` is assigned `0x80`. Assuming 8-bit bytes, its value in binary representation, is `10000000`. Apparently, on your platform, `char` is a signed type. So, `0x80` (i.e. `10000000`) corresponds to -128.

When `<<` is applied to a `char` value, it is promoted to `int` and the sign is preserved. So, when shifted once to the left, with 32-bit integers, it becomes `11111111111111111111111100000000` (two's complement) which is -256.

Comment: The promotion to `int` is nothing to do with `printf` in this instance; it's due to the `<<`.  Also, that's not the representation of -256 in either one's or two's complement.

Answer (score 1):

Just a side-note.  From a bottom up perspective, bit-wise shifting (and masking) is based on an architecture's word-length (expressed in bits).  The length of a word, varies from architecture to architecture.

[See this Wiki page for word lengths by architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computing%29)

If one knows the word length of the target architecture, one can use bit-shifting to multiply, and divide (in some cases), faster than using operands.

[See this Wiki page for interesting diagrams of bit-shifting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#cite_note-0)

Since bit-shifted code is architecture dependent, one cannot assume a specific piece of bit-shifted code will work the same way from architecture to architecture.  However, once one is familiar with the idea of different word lengths for different architectures, bit-shifting becomes less mysterious and more predictable.

Thankfully, today we have 8, 16, 32, and 64 bit word lengths, and exclusively 8 bit character lengths.  In the days of ancient computing, an architecture might have a 12, or a 15, or a 23 bit word length (etc., ad nauseum).

Comment: Thanku Mike sir for sharing this information.You all have great knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why your compiler do not complain with a warning that 0x80 does not fit in char, which on your platform can represent only values from -0x80 to 0x7F.

Try this piece of code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <limits.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main() {
      printf("char can represent values from %d to %d.\n", CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX);
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

Your situation is called OVERFLOW.